# Cannot load HTML link content on server, but on local machine it works

Tags: java, php, html

there is a link to a video file, something like this:

```
<a href="http://a.aaaaa.com/key=jpmsOkrvFb7,end=3310886438/data=58BC2222/speed=150k/1111111.mp4" download="" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

But If i try to download it from my local or remote server, instead of video I get dummy: "this video was removed" and so on.
But link perfectly works if i just create blank html file with the same link in file system and open it with browser.
I also found a service that works with such links, but requires java. When you give such link to the service (http://tubeoffline.com), he gives you new link with such format:

```
127.0.0.1: 432434/FFF.FLV
```

Can anybody say how it is done?.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the request URL and parameters, there is more information in a HTTP request received by a server: The accepted contents and languages, the implied cookie, authorization info, cache info, and... the USER AGENT.

Most likely, if a server endpoint wants to find out if the request comes from a navigator or a batch program, he will read first the "user-agent" HTTP header and check it against most well-known navigators.

Comment: I solved this issue with streaming video from our server to users' browser.